# Regular expression appears to ignore tab character

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that parses lines in a driver inf file to extract just the variable names and values ignoring whitespace and end of line comments that begin with a semicolon.

It looks like this:

```
"^([^=\s]+)[ ]*=[ ]*([^;\r\n]+)(?<! )"
```

Most of the time it works just fine as per the example here: [regex example 1](http://regex101.com/r/oX7vW4/1)

However, when it encounters a line that has a tab character anywhere between the variable name and the equals sign, the expression fails as per the example here: [regex example 2](http://regex101.com/r/tV8oH3/1)

I have tried replacing "\s" with "\t" and "\x09" and it still doesnt work. I have edited the text file that contains the tab character with a hex editor and confirmed that it is indeed ASCII "09". I don't want to use a positive character match as the variable could actually contain quite a large number of special characters.

The appearance of the literal "=" seems to cause the problem but I cannot understand why.
For example, if I strip back the expression to this: [regex example 3](http://regex101.com/r/mC5fN8/1)

and use the line with the tab character in it, it works fine. But as soon as I add the literal "=" as per the example here: [regex example 4](http://regex101.com/r/nI4yE1/1), it no longer matches, appearing to ignore the tab character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `[ ]*` match only space characters (`U+0020` SPACE) and not other whitespace characters.
Change both to `[ \t]*` to match tabs as well. The result would now look like:

```
"^([^=\s]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*([^;\r\n]+)(?<! )"
```

Comment: That fixed it but for something different I tried "^([^\s]+)=" in the first part and it doesnt work. I thought "^([^\s]+)=" meant "from the beginning of the string, match everything that is not a whitespace until you get to the literal "=""?

Comment: @Lembasts `^([^\s]+)=`this wont work coz before `=` there is `space`.So there is nothing to consume space as you have denied space consumption.Therefore it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You've just added the `\t` tab character in the wrong part I think.

This was your example 2 (not working):

```
^([^=\s]+)[ ]*=[ ]*([^;\r\n]+)(?<! )
```

This is your example 2 ... working (with a tab):

```
^([^=\s]+)[ \t]*=[ ]*([^;\r\n]+)(?<! )
            ^^ tab here
```

Seems to do the trick and match your first example: http://regex101.com/r/kQ1zH4/1

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^=\s]+)\s*=\s*([^;\r\n]+)(?<!\s)
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tV8oH3/2